# :after node is not visible with text overflow ellipsis

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to show an indicator (orange dot) to signify that an operation has occurred on the list item. I am also using `overflow: hidden;` and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to take care of text overflow.

The issue I am facing is that when text overflow happens the indicator is not visible.

```css
.root {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
}

li .name {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

li .name:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="name">
        This is one
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="name">
        This is one
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="name">
        This is one
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="name">
        This Long Long Long Long Text Is Here
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Code pen: https://codepen.io/anilnamde/pen/vmbzJa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why is this happening

The pseudo element is treated as `inline-block` content which means it is positioned directly after the text.

### What can you do?

You can force the pseudo element to show by taking it out of the document flow with `position: absolute;` and positioning it at the end of the `.name` container.

The following changes are required:

- Add `position: relative;` and `padding-right: 10px;` to `li .name`, this will position the pseudo element relatively to it and provide some breathing space
- Add `position: absolute;`, `right: 2px;`, `top: 0;`, `bottom: 0;` and `margin: auto;` to position the pseudo element at the end of `.name`

```css
.root {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
}

li .name {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

li .name:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background: orange;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="name">
        This is one
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="name">
        This is one
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="name">
        This is one
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="name">
        This Long Long Long Long Text Is Here
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the when there is a long text , the orange dot is at the end of the text.You can verify that by giving `position:absolute` to the `:after` element.
[image]

You can do something like this to avoid that.

```css
.root {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  position:relative;
}
li .name {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
li .name:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background: orange;
  position : absolute;
  z-index:3;
  right:2px;
  top:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <ul>
  <li>
      <div class="name">
        This is one
      </div>
    </li>
      <li>
      <div class="name">
        This is one
      </div>
    </li>
  <li>
      <div class="name">
        This is one
      </div>
    </li>
  <li>
      <div class="name">
        This Long Long Long Long Text Is Here
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it use `position: relative` to `li .name` and position the `li .name:after` absolute to it. Give  a little `padding-right:15px` to `li .name`.

**SNIPPET**

```css
    .root {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
}
li .name {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position:relative;
  padding-right:15px;
}
li .name:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    background: orange;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 40%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: calc(100% - 10px);
    
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <ul>
  <li>
      <div class="name">
        This is one
      </div>
    </li>
      <li>
      <div class="name">
        This is one
      </div>
    </li>
  <li>
      <div class="name">
        This is one
      </div>
    </li>
  <li>
      <div class="name">
        This Long Long Long Long Text Is Here
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can absolute position the pseudo element relative to the .name element

```css
li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  .name {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    &:after {
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      width: 6px;
      height: 6px;
      background: orange;
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      top: 7px;
    }
  }
}
```